# Open html file with Workbooks.Open allways in new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I use Workbooks.Open method to open local html file in excel. This method opens file in new workbook, so then I copy UsedRange into my current Workbook's ActiveSheet. Everything works fine except when I turn on Excel for the first time, do not modify any cell in it and press the button (in my custom add-in (xlam)) to open this html file. In this case, the file opens in the **current sheet**. How can I achieve to allways open this external file in other workbook or other sheet? Here is my code sample:

```
Dim tempWorkbook As Workbook
Set tempWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("file:///C:/report.html")
```

This code opens html file in another workbook only if current active sheet was modified, but opens in current workbook if it was not modified by user before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
This now puts the setting back to original value.

You could tell Excel that the current workbook isn't saved - forcing it to keep it in place when it opens the HTML file. The below example checks that it's called Book1 before doing so:

```
Dim savedsetting As Boolean
Dim tempWorkbook As Workbook
Dim curWorkbook As Workbook

Set curWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
savedsetting = curWorkbook.Saved

If curWorkbook.Name = "Book1" Then curWorkbook.Saved = False
Set tempWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("file:///C:/report.html")
if curWorkbook.Saved <> savedsetting then curWorkbook.Saved = savedsetting
```

Comment: Then a user will always be prompted to save original workbook.

Comment: Good point @Eugene - I've amended the code to put it back immediately after now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Dim sFile$
Dim tempWorkbook As Workbook

sFile = "file:///C:/report.html"
Set tempWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add(Template:=sFile)
```

Then the workbook will be open as a template, but *still retain original name*. Original file won't be locked and can be moved.
It would be good to save it with a new name in a next step.

If it won't work with html (I tested it with xlsx), then you can do the following:

```
Dim sFile$
Dim tempWorkbook As Workbook

sFile = "file:///C:/report.html"
Set tempWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add
tempWorkbook.Activate 'Activates new workbook
Set tempWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(sFile) 'opens a file
```

Set a separate variable if new workbook is still blank after opening html - you would want to close it then.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Workbooks.Add Method?
If I implement it into my Custom Bar and Use a different test file it works.

```
Sub
   Dim tempWorkbook As Workbook
   Set tempWorkbook = Workbooks.Add("file:///C:/report.html")
End
```

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't work for me. The original 'Book1' still closed.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted @CLR answer, but actually this implementation has one drawback. If user turns on excel initialy he/she has empty workbook named "Book1". If he/she creates another empty workbook "Book2" and tries to open html file, when it opens on workbook "Book1", but not on new workbook. So I modified the suggested code like this:

Before open html file:

```
For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count
   ReDim Preserve savedSettings(i)
   savedSettings(i - 1) = Workbooks(i).Saved
   Workbooks(i).Saved = False
Next
```

After open, after copied and closed TEMP (html) workbook:

```
For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count
    Workbooks(i).Saved = savedSettings(i - 1)
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Saved = False
```